# How do I execute a function once a google form is finished inside a webview?

Tags: swift, google-forms

I am using Google Forms in my swift app. The user is supposed to click a button, and then go into a webview to complete the form. The problem is that, once the user completes the form, they are stuck on the finish page. I don't want to add a navigation controller in my app because the user would then be able to skip the form. I am having issues finding ways to make a function that is executed once the form is finished. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found way to workaround the issue by providing a link at the end of the google form to finish the form. The webview would then recognize the changed url.